# Research topics satisfying categories: tablet / security 2012

Tags: android, ipad, security, blackberry

I've been googling for a month now, and before that for 2 weeks, but now my research supervisor is telling me that me research topic, which is along the lines of "what security holes do mobile AV software have to fill to meet the security standards of current workstations", is too obvious and that there is no real problem for which i want to prvide a solution. He suggested I focus on tablets alone and the move from current workstations to tablets and the security risks that come with it,

I want a topic that would be more clearer and appealing to me though, that would include finding security holes in tablets and their software etc. for instance "using a tablet as a vessel to infiltrate the network" or "the tablet as a hacking tool".

But I'm trying to validate my topic or find problems that I'll be solving in my research in that direction when i do go that way, so that I don't fail in my presentation.

google's not giving me anything to help, Is there any place I can find Current problems in teblet/networking security that includes tablets in comparison to workstation/PC security?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

Your thesis would probably end up being something along the lines of "There are unique problems presented with computer and data security when dealing with mobile devices as opposed to desktops..." at which point you would conclude whether or not the benefits of using a mobile device outweigh the risks of doing so. Be sure to note cost advantages/disadvantages of using mobile devices as well.

This is an interesting topic and there's a ton of information on it.

Here are a handful of interesting things to look into:

- How [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) has standardized communications between a web service
  and a non-native client.
- The [iOS jailbreaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking) "scene".
- The [Android rooting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_%28Android_OS%29) "scene".
- How virus's have been distributed to mobile devices by way of
  applications imitating other applications.
- How mobile applications may easily steal data (location, contacts,
  even text messages) from ignorant users. How can you protect users
  from unknowingly giving up their data?
- The security pro's and con's of choosing either iOS, Android,
  Windows, or Blackberry mobile devices. (Ultimately, no platform is perfect)
- How to protect and retrieve your data if your mobile device is lost or stolen

Start small and work your way up. With some effort, you should be able to come up with a comprehensive, thorough look at security practices used by mobile devices. You'll probably learn a lot too. Good luck!